# Edditing gnome-shell.css doesn't changes the appearance

Tags: shell, fedora, gnome

So i've edited gnome-shell.css to change the top bar text color to blue and background color to white but it doesn't do it. 
https://postimg.org/image/8lioi30yf/   [gnome-shell.css][1]
I resterted shell ,restarted pc. What am i doing wrong?
I am using fedora 25